# Invertible Matrices over Local Rings (Nakayama's Lemma)

Tags: commutative-algebra

Prove that if $M$ is an $n \times n$ invertible matrix over a local ring $R$, with coefficients in the maximal ideal $m$, then $m+M$ is invertible.

It seems by Nakayama's lemma that if $M$ is invertible, it should at least span the $R/m$ vector space $R^n/mR^n$, however, since its coefficients come from $m$ it will be 0 here. Is my thinking off somewhere?

I found this question on a list of questions students reported being asked on their qualifying exams.

**Update**: If the matrix has coefficients in $m$, it will not be invertible. So, suppose $M$ has entries in $R$ and is invertible. Is it then true that for any matrix $N$ over $m$, the matrix $M+N$ is invertible?

Comment: If the coefficients are in the maximal ideal, the matrix will not be invertible.

Comment: How do you add $m$ (an ideal in $R$) and a matrix?

Comment: My guess would be that he is supposed to show that the sum of an invertible matrix and a matrix with all coefficients in the maximal ideal is again invertible.

Comment: Ok, this seems right. I will update the question to reflect the rephrasing of the question.

Comment: A matrix over a local ring is invertible iff it is invertible after passing to the residue field. This immediately proves your statement.